In a Blazor Hybrid App. How do I set the initial page inside the webview while still using the layout
In the MainLayout.razor page you have a @body which will by default show the control with a @page "/" at the top. I would like to dynamically set it to this page or a different page depending on custom logic.
If I try to set the page at the BlazorWebView control (in MainPage.xaml) it will then show the page but without the layout (MainLayout.razor)
I tried the following in the Routes.razor page too but it did not work:
@inject NavigationManager _NavigationManager

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(MauiProgram).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //this would have logic to set startupPage in reality
        var startupPage = "/help";
        _NavigationManager.NavigateTo(startupPage);
    }
}

So just to reiterate. I would like the @body to render as an initial page what I want depending on logic and not the @page "/" page
Thanks

Maybe you can take a look at the nestead layout. You can render a specific layout accordingly to some logic

Here is my solution but I hope there is a simpler one.
In the MainLayout.razor page I have
<main id="main">
@if (showAlternateContent && firstLoad)
{
    <MyApp.Components.Pages.MyPage></MyApp.Components.Pages.MyPage>
} else {
    @Body
}
</main>

...
@code {
    public static bool firstLoad = true;
    private bool showAlternateContent = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (MyConditionIsMet)
        {
            showAlternateContent = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        firstLoad = false;
    }
}

